# Scaling and rotating images on a Canvas on Android

Tags: android

How do you scale and rotate images on a Canvas on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This might](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html) help you do what you want to do.

Comment: It is generally considered helpful to summarise the answer here, as well as linking to an external site.

Comment: @ingsaurabh the provided link is not working anymore!

Answer (score 0):

To draw scaled and rotated images on an Android Canvas you need something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    getResources(), R.drawable.myimg );

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate( 90.0f );     // Degrees
matrix.preScale( 1.5f, 1.5f ); // 1.0f would be no scaling

Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap, matrix, paint );

surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost( canvas );
```

Or, to keep hold of a scaled and rotated bitmap for later use, create one like this:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    oldBitmap, 0, 0, oldBitmap.getWidth(),
    oldBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true );
```

More details: [Canvas.drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint%29), [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html), [Bitmap.createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29)

Tutorial here: [Canvas and Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)

Answer (score -1):

you can use sample code at developer site .in which particularly [api demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) will help u abt this topic.